# How to calculate timeframes using 24 hour time

Tags: javascript

I have a spreadsheet that lists various employee shifts, with one column for start time and another for end time (in 24-hour military time). I need to be able to run a function to calculate how long each shift is. I am sure I am way over thinking this because I am very stuck. Below is the function that I have so far but unfortunately for an 8 hour shift it comes back as undefined:

```
// Desired result for a shift from 0500-1300, 1300-2100 or 2100-0500 would be "8:00"

Logger.log(calculate8hours(500, 1300))

function calculate8hours (x, y) {

if ( (y-x) >0) {
  let hour = (String((y - x) / 100)).split(".")[0];
  let minutes = (String((y - x) / 100)).split(".")[1];
  return `${hour}:${minutes}`
} else {
  return (((2400-x) + y)) /100;
};

};
```

Comment: In your example you have a string (because it has a leading zero like `0500`) in the comment but a number (`500`) in the code. What is the datatype that you are really dealing with? String or Integer?

Comment: They originate as numbers, I converted it to a String to workaround an error stating the "split" was not a function

Comment: Well it comes back as `8:undefined` because if you are inspecting the result of `((y - x) / 100)` with `x` = 500 and `y` = 1300 you will see that it simply returns `8`. Not a decimal number with a separator as you would expect it. So accessing `[1]` will yield `undefined`.

Comment: Ah I see... I suppose then for the [1] I would have to have another ternary operator depending on wether it's defined or not. If it is, then it would return the minutes and if not, it would return Two 0's

Comment: That's one way of doing it 

Comment: I should have hit the books a little harder in math class lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with time, no matter what the human readable format is, always convert it to a single numeric value, with sufficient precision (usually seconds or milliseconds, but in your case minutes will do), when doing calculation. Only convert back to human readable format when you are going to display it.

```js
function militaryToMinutes(t)
{
  return Math.floor(t/100) * 60 + (t % 100);
}


function duration(x,y)
{
  let deltaMin = militaryToMinutes(y) - militaryToMinutes(x);
  if(deltaMin < 0)
  {
    deltaMin += 24 * 60;
  }
  const h = Math.floor(deltaMin/60);
  const m = (deltaMin % 60);
  return `${h}:${("0"+m).slice(-2)}`;
}

console.log(duration(500,1300));
console.log(duration(2100,500));
```

Comment: Got it, I did have it in the back of my mind to calculate the number of minutes first. This will actually help with other calculations I will have to run later on

Answer (score 1):

Here's a functional solution without dependencies. I explain using comments in the code. Note that it is designed only to work with ranges <= 24 hours:

[Code in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAExsYAJOIBOBnRACjygEMcoAVGAWwFMAuREnGMAc0QB9EwQaARnRwAaRHTDJq9JizacefQcICUsqKw6IA3gChEiAPSHEAYQQA3YVERsADiCgEocXvyH59zMhWl1EALyIduR4dACSYFDEPlS0-qQEchxiAIwADCoA3F4SUvGBwaERUYR5foiJ3prsaZk5XsaIAGqkADYwyKRQ-vaOeF4QCCTe5FBYuARBALLdABYAdMBtcHA4MWMVJhn1XmhEJGMT+IgAfIgATADMKohQczhwAO68dC8AojiP6wDkkRbtTqjCiIObYHA-bKDYY2PLHKaIWb3JYrNZlSRbRA7KEGfbo5Dws6XG53B7PV4fL5ov5gAEdZDiSSg8GQnIGIZgEaHCjTNiOOgI7lxeiIACkWPS6TZtmAB1ivL4PQI5wArABOW73R4vMBvRCfb6EGl0oFCxA0PlK1nQzmwyQK-kI8oFcU7aV4vIOpVE9Wask6vUG6n-QEMvLmy0C62NEwAcToNlQ6GEEgg-iEUCedAkzMmYlIyFQWguABYZaS6ABPRAQR54AgW5BgGDsOZQLxtBO5k5BOHgggAWmB4377tlhDBk0QAB5EJluwQANRBUsNAxNeOJtDAFOQdMJrM5i2KgX5wvyRAANnS5d17G6MCsRAEa21F9ISEnOBUHa7x8dhSepGg7Dl6ApjkQ-7erO856AYBhQQKiDLleUpeAYX6DkEqTSgAvroXg4AmuBIAABgAJNomG4QwlEAMoaPIhCIXgKgLCEyAMWMhAXGIPzpJCuGkTk+G6E0ABijw0IglbgogACOIACrACAMGJJgACICjAREMkReAgG0NjAGslTMHMaDGVJc4qpKA6pFckppI56QDhcOyIKZ7l2ektk3k82BtAyQiIAARAAHAwkqhQRHIjPphlQKkhRJpg-aEH5zmSlCcVwJ2CwrOwhAJUZqTZEYJihekkXRbFMKICVUAXCl27woQDlOZc2I5Ll+WFcVAqJRc5VNFVNXpDFuhxTYjVXC16Btd56RiH5OXDHldAFXARWzSNlXVVFE26EAA)

```js
function diffHours (startTime, endTime) {
  // Convert inputs to numbers in the case that they're provided as strings
  startTime = parseInt(startTime, 10);
  endTime = parseInt(endTime, 10);

  // Validate inputs
  const startHours = Math.floor(startTime / 100);
  if (startHours > 23) throw new Error('Invalid start hour');
  const endHours = Math.floor(endTime / 100);
  if (endHours > 23) throw new Error('Invalid end hour');
  const startMinutes = startTime % 100;
  if (startMinutes > 59) throw new Error('Invalid start minutes');
  const endMinutes = endTime % 100;
  if (endMinutes > 59) throw new Error('Invalid end minutes');

  // Get difference between hours, adding 24 if they cross midnight
  let hours = endHours - startHours;
  if (hours < 0) hours += 24;

  // Get difference between minutes, adding 60 if negative (borrowing an hour)
  let minutes = endMinutes - startMinutes;
  if (minutes < 0) {
    minutes += 60;
    hours -= 1;
  }

  return `${hours}:${String(minutes).padStart(2, '0')}`;
}

// From your question:
// Desired result for a shift from 0500-1300, 1300-2100 or 2100-0500 would be "8:00"

const result1 = diffHours(500, 1300);
console.log(result1); // "8:00"

const result2 = diffHours(1300, 2100);
console.log(result2); // "8:00"

const result3 = diffHours(2100, 500);
console.log(result3); // "8:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get any result what you want regarding the time, please use moment.js or moment npm module.

```
var duration = moment.duration(end.diff(startTime));
var hours = duration.asHours();
```

If you use moment module or js, you can get diff time by using the above code.